# D-PAD using css and html

Tags: html, css

I want to style these 4 buttons into a cross form like a D-Pad. I tried it and it somehow didn't look like I expected it to do. I'm a bit new to the whole html and css stuff.
For context I am trying to build a 2048 game as a webapp and I thought I would do a D-pad for it to work on mobile.

```css
div#btn-container {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: 600px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  background-color: black;
}

button#left {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 200px;
}

button#up {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}

button#down {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 400px;
}

button#right {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div id="btn-container">
  <button id="left"></button>
  <button id="up"></button>
  <button id="down"></button>
  <button id="right"></button>
</div>
```

Comment: Please read how to place elements in grid. Use that and not margins of enormous sizes: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/

Answer (score 1):

As @Justinas said, you'll probably want to use CSS grid to achieve this styling. Here is an example to get you started. Notice specifically that a 3x3 grid was defined, and then `grid-xxx-start` was used to put each button in the appropriate location.

```css
div#btn-container {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  display: grid;
  grid: 133px 133px 133px / 133px 133px 133px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  background-color: black;
  place-items: center center;
}

button#left {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  grid-row-start: 2;
  grid-column-start: 1;
}

button#up {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  grid-row-start: 1;
  grid-column-start: 2;
}

button#down {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  grid-row-start: 3;
  grid-column-start: 2;
}

button#right {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  grid-row-start: 2;
  grid-column-start: 3;
}
```

```html
<div id="btn-container">
  <button id="left">L</button>
  <button id="up">U</button>
  <button id="down">D</button>
  <button id="right">R</button>
</div>
```

Comment: worked like a charm thank you. However, the Distance between each button seems like much. Do I modify that by resizing the grid cells or is there a defined distance between each cell?

Comment: Right now, there is no container-level gap between the cells (see [the `gap` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/gap) for that). The spacing you see is a side effect of the button size (100px) and `place-items` declaration (centered within 133px cell size). You can adjust all of those as necessary, even using percentages to achieve a more responsive setup.

Answer (score 1):

**Layout**

For a *flexbox* (FBL) approach it is easiest to create a main FBL container containing three FBL child containers for the buttons.

- The first and third FBL child containers are just one button wide, horizontally centered in the main FBL container.
- The second FBL child container is three buttons wide holding only two buttons, pushed apart with `justify-content: space-between`

**Sizing**

- The button sizes can be any value, but I used *linear equation* **y = mx + b** to calculate a size relative to the current viewport minimum size (vmin). At vmin 240px the button size is 70px and at vmin 1080px it is 245px. With points (240,70) and (1080,245) the equation is: **y = 0.20833x + 20**. In CSS, converted to `rem`: `calc(20.834vmin + 1.25rem)`
- The same goes for the button font size. At vmin 360px the font size is 12px and at vmin 1080px it is 16px. Points (360,12) and (1080,16) yield equation **y = 0.00555x + 10**. CSS: `calc(0.556vmin + 0.625rem)`

**Snippet**

```css
.D-Pad {
    /* define variable sizes depending on current minimum viewport size */
    /* using linear equation y = mx + b for points (x1,y1) and (x2,y2) */
    --button-size: calc(20.834vmin + 1.25rem); /* (240,70)(1080,245) */
    --button-text: calc(0.556vmin + 0.625rem); /* (360,12)(1080, 16) */
}

.D-Pad, .D-Pad>* {
    /* Default Flexbox row containers */
    display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center;
}
.D-Pad, .btn-col {
    /* Flexbox column containers */
    flex-direction: column;
}
.btn-col {
    width: var(--button-size)
}
.btn-row { 
    width: calc(3 * var(--button-size)); /* creates center space */
    justify-content: space-between;      /* push buttons to either side */
}
.btn-col > *,  /* Using wildcards so any element will work, not only <button> */
.btn-row > * {
    font-size: var(--button-text);

    width: var(--button-size);
    aspect-ratio: 1; /* make it a square */
}

/* Just demo */
*             { box-sizing: border-box }
body          { margin: 0; min-height: 100vh }
body, .center { display: grid; place-items: center; text-align: center }
.center       { padding: 0.5em }
```

```html
<div class="D-Pad">
    <div class="btn-col"><button>top</button></div>
    <div class="btn-row">
        <button>left</button>
        <div class="center">optional center element</div>
        <button>right</button>
    </div>
    <div class="btn-col"><button>bottom</button></div>
</div>
```